# How To Prevent Maven from Giving Out My Password to Everybody

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

We have a Jenkins that runs Maven on some GIT projects. It's bad enough that Jenkins prints the password when printing the command line it executes, but that is small and hidden and I guess I can live with that. What is horrible on so many levels is the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project org.acme.project.build: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://UserName:Password@bitbucket.acme.org/scm/moda/project.build.git/'
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

Yes, the Maven release plug-in prints my username and password on the command line. That's unacceptable. I don't even know why I have to ask this question.

How do I get the `maven-release-plugin` to not print my password like this? (Alternatively: how do I get Jenkins to not print it?)

Comment: A quick fix would be to give Jenkins its own account.  Then it would at least not be printing your username and password.

Comment: Big issue here is also why are you using unencrypted HTTP for these connections since then your password can possibly be grabbed from the network by a third party? Have you written the auth info into the URL manually or is the plugin generating that?

Comment: @GabeSechan Still it means giving out sensitive data (to release a user must have read and write access to our repositories).

Comment: @SteffiS. Agreed.  It was meant more as a quick hack to get your data out.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The plug-in is generating that. And I see no reason whatsover for ever using the URL over using the "Authorization" field of the request header.